# Oracle Sql timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I've a application which generates the queries dynamically for any GUI data changes. I am using http://openhms.sourceforge.net/sqlbuilder/ APIs for this.

Everything is working as long as I am not using timestamp columns.

When there is a timestamp column, it generates the queries like

```
UPDATE table 
SET col1= 'junk' 
WHERE MESSAGE = 'Garbage')
  AND CREATED_DATE_TIME = {ts '2013-10-01 07:09:54.342'}
  AND LAST_UPDATED_DATE_TIME = NULL
  AND ACK_TIME = NULL
```

It gets executed but data (col1) is not getting updated. The data gets updated if I remove timestamp column (CREATED_DATE_TIME) from the condition.

Any clue?

Comment: Is there any error? Probably something is wrong with this kind of timestamp notation. Can you maybe force this tool to use other format/notation?

Comment: Does a record exist with the exact timestamp of '2013-10-01 07:09:54.342'?

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause is returning no rows, hence forbidding an update. Reconsider your filtering conditions, because filtering by a timestamp will filter all the records that do not match the provided value, even by a fraction of a second.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rachcha. Problem is my SqlBuilder API does not handle very well and hence generated a query having `LAST_UPDATED_DATE_TIME = NULL`. Ideally, it should have been generated as `LAST_UPDATED_DATE_TIME *IS* NULL`

I did not notice that unless I read Rachcha's comment.